# Running Oracle 11g as non root user

Tags: oracle, centos6

I installed Oracle 11g on CentOS-7. Now my requirement is to run Oracle server from a normal user. I have root access and if required I can do the changes to run the server but at later stage I would like non root users to start the server.

Kindly suggest if there is any way around.

regards
Mohtashim

Comment: Why did you tag this with sql server 2008 ?

Comment: Sorry its my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The Oracle installation instructions specify that you must create linux groups and users for it. You should use those users.

Comment: Thanks Cristian for your answer. Can you please point me to that documentation which explains the procedure.